# AJAX Request flow in case of CORS

Tags: ajax, cors

If I  hit any AJAX request on targeting server then the request directly goes to targeting server or the request first goes to origin server and then goes to targeting server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-origin AJAX requests go directly from your browser to what you call the “targeting server”.

A cross-origin AJAX request is initiated by JavaScript running in your browser on the client side after the browser fetches the JavaScript for your Web application/document from the origin server.

A cross-origin AJAX request does not go back to the origin server ever. The communication is: JavaScript running in your browser sends a request to the “targeting” server, which replies with a response directly back to the browser and back to your JavaScript running on the client side.